# Laravel 4: Autoload Helpers in Modules

Tags: laravel-4, autoload, helper

I have created multiple modules in the application like:

```
/app
   /modules
      events
      sections
      programs
```

The problem is i must have to use common helpers like View, Input, Auth etc. in the controller of each module like:

```
namespace App\Modules\Sections\Controllers;

use View,Input,Auth,Config,Session,Redirect,App,Request;

class SectionsController extends \BaseController{
  ....
  ....
}
```

If i don't add them at the top of the controller then gets below example error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

Class 'App\Modules\Sections\Controllers\View' not found
```

What i need to do so that i don't have to add all those helpers manually in each controller?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: I don't want to add all helpers manually in each controller

Comment: Maybe use the classes like this: \Input::all()

Comment: By prefixing \ it worked for me... Is there any other best way available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way to access global namespace is to prefixing the class name with a backward slash:

```
\Input::all()
```